# bad practice for Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types

I created my CPT along with your category ... It's a bad practice to do this?

in register_post_type: `rewrite => array ( 'slug' => 'portfolio/work' )`

in register_taxonomy: `rewrite => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio/categoty' );`

The reason is that my URL looks like this:

```
mysite.com/portfolio/work-title
mysite.com/portfolio/category/weddings
```

Comment: If that's the URL you want then it's not a bad practice and is fine.

Comment: Nope. It's absolutely fine. I've done this myself without issue.